# For loop is not working properly in nodejs

Tags: node.js, for-loop

I am using diffbot api along in for loop

this is my code

```
for (var i = 0; i< 200; i++){
    /* pass url from diffbot */
    console.log("Ready to send Url for parsing to Diffbot ");

    diffbot.article({ uri: url }, function(err, response) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(i);
        } else {
            console.log("Error Occur in url " + i + "and error is " + err);
            /* need to Add logic for parsing  */
        }
    });
}
```

Now I got console message like

```
output is coming 

200 
200
200
200
200
```

**two hundred times.**

**output is expected 0 to 199**

Does any body tell me where I am wrong

Thanks

Comment: why we need clousure.. Can u please explain

Comment: By the time the statement `console.log(i);` executed, value of `i` is 200, because of asynchronous callback. You need a closure to "keep" the desired value of `i` at the time statement `diffbot.article(...)` executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 200; ++ i) {
     diffbot.article ({ uri: url }, (function (i) { 
         return function (err, response) { ... }
     })(i)); 
 }
```

This will work.

Comment: why you add function(i) {  here. can u pls explain

Comment: @Kamalpreet See http://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/2129835. Short answer: Closures.

Answer (score 3):

What happens is simple:

Your loop makes 200 posts. The response gets executed for each post asynchronously, meaning that all posts may be done by the time the first response arrives, executing the callback function. Therefore, `i==200` by then.

Elaborating a bit after your comment:

You'll need a closure to keep the current value of `i` by the time you get the response, as stated in fzzle's answer:

```
 diffbot.article({ uri: url }, (function(i) { 
         return function(err, response) {
         ... }
     })(i));
```

Enclosing your callback function in `function(i){ ... }` creates the closure. This way, the current value of i is passed to the function, and then available for response with the value you want, whenever this response will come back.

Comment: @Kamalpreet, he did understand your problem .. you don't.

Comment: I did, google for asynchronous, and closures. @fzzle's answer is what you need to do to fix your code.

Comment: may be i am wrong.. why we need asynchronous and closures

Comment: Your code is already asynchronous, so you need a closure to keep the current value of i by the time you get the response.

Comment: Can you please explain me, how do u know my code is asynchronous and why we need Closure